# CD / DVD drive pops out automatically

Tags: dvd, cd-drive

I am using a Dell Vostro 2520 laptop, with Ubuntu 16.04 (which I use primarily) and Windows 10 dual boot. Of late, my CD / DVD drive keeps popping out for no particular reason, and no particular time. Any fixes?
p.s. I dont want to disable my drive like [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1310633/cd-dvd-drive-auto-ejects).

Comment: As the other user said: "Have you tried remove it from the BIOS boot order?". Also, you don't need to disable your CD drive. Just [*disable*](https://superuser.com/questions/334338/disable-cd-rom-in-bios) the "effect of the eject button"

Comment: This happens in both OS?

Comment: I couldn't find it in my BIOS boot order. Also, I haven't opened my windows OS for a number of months now, so don't know about whether it would also have the same effect there.

Comment: You didn't find it in BIOS? That's weird.. are you sure?

Comment: Well, I might have looked in the wrong place. I pressed F12 while restarting, took me to BIOS settings, there secure boot was off and from there i went to setup, couldnt find anything about CD/DVD drive. To say the truth, I have not much idea where to look

Comment: @pritmit - You need to boot into Windows, to determine if it's happening with Windows or just Linux, the answer to your question would change significantly if this behavior is exhibited in both operating systems.  Once you have determined if that is or isn't the case, you should edit your question, it will help formulate an answer.